# Proving a weak convergence theorem using ascoli's theorem proof

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

**Theorem:** Let $(H, \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a separable Hilbert space. Let $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence such that $x_n\in H$ and $\|x_n\|\leqslant 1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then, there exist a subsequence $(x_{j(n)})$ and $x\in H$ such that
$$
x_{j(n)} \rightarrow x \mbox{ weakly in }\ H.
$$
To prove this theorem, I need to do the following steps:

1. For $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we suppose $f_n: H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_n(z)=\langle x_n, z\rangle$ for all $z\in H$. Show that the weak convergence will return to show the simple convergence of f with close extraction.
2. Taking the inspiration from the proof of Ascoli's theorem, we will show that there exists $f ∈ H'$ and a subsequence $(f_{j(n)})$ such that $(f_{j(n)})$ converges simply to $f$. There will be a small diagional process of Cantor. It will be simpler than Ascoli actually.
3. We will go back to H with a well-chosen theorem.

What we need here is to prove this theorem, but for that we will prove the fthree steps mentioned above. I face a problem in find a solution for this theorem. Does anyone can help me?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1179395/588038)?

Comment: @ThomasShelby thank you for the comment. It can help to prove the weak convergence of the subsequence $x_{j(n)}$. But what am searching on is to prove it using the above three steps. especially step 2.